# undefined symbol: EVP_idea_cbc when using wget

Tags: wget, openssl

When  try to run this  `sudo  wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz` I get the error below:

```
wget: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by wget)
wget: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by wget)
URL transformed to HTTPS due to an HSTS policy
--2019-02-24 23:46:26--  https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1.tar.gz
wget: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: undefined symbol: EVP_idea_cbc
```

Comment: Why run it with sudo?

Comment: You should not have SSL library in `/usr/local/`, this library should be in its normal place (*/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0*). What is your Ubuntu version? Please add output of `apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0` .

Comment: This is my ubuntu version  `1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.14`

Comment: "Why run it with sudo". I tried it with or without there is no difference on the output.

Comment: @MichaleRezene then please don't run it with. You should _never_ run a command with `sudo` unless you know it is necessary. This isn't a solution to your issue, it's just general advice.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a custom build of wget that statically links to /usr/local?

Can you run `which wget` to get the full path to wget. The output might look something like

```
$ which wget
/usr/bin/wget
```

Then use `ldd` and pass it that full path. E.g. `ldd /usr/bin/wget`

The output should look something like this:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/wget 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffcc3bfd000)
    libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 (0x00007f4f516da000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f4f51468000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f4f51261000)
    libidn2.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 (0x00007f4f51044000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007f4f50dda000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007f4f50962000)
    libpsl.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpsl.so.5 (0x00007f4f50754000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f4f50363000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f4f5015f000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f4f4ff40000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f4f51b62000)
    libunistring.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 (0x00007f4f4fbc2000)
```

`ldd` is telling you where the executable (wget) is looking for its dynamically linked libraries i.e. the `.so` files that it depends on.

If you are using a custom build of wget which expects the .so libraries to be in /usr/local, you will have to install those yourself somehow outside of the package manager.

If you want to use the version of wget from the package manager repositories which will look in the expected lib directories (similar to mine above) you should install it with something like `sudo apt-get install wget`