# Why does wget fail with "wget: symbol lookup error: wget: undefined symbol: psl_str_to_utf8lower"?

Tags: apt, package-management, wget

On a brand new installation of Ubuntu Linux 18.04, `wget <URL>` fails with,

```
wget: symbol lookup error: wget: undefined symbol: psl_str_to_utf8lower
```

I have tested that the resource exists at the URL, is accessible via Web browser, and can be retrieved with `wget` installations on other machines.

Removing `wget` and reinstalling via the APT package manager did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

<s>As it turns out, `libpsl` is not installed because it is not an explicit dependency of `wget` it seems. Installing the library with `sudo apt-get install libpsl-dev` resolved my issue.</s>

---

**Update**

I encountered the issue again on a new session and thought it weird. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling both `wget` and `libpsl-dev` to no avail. After a bit more searching, I stumbled upon a hint in [this answer to a somewhat related question](https://askubuntu.com/a/1120984/743914): after running `ldd /usr/bin/wget`, I saw that `wget` was linking to a copy of `libpsl` that is part of an external package I use for a project I work on (more to the point, I was modifying my environment variables by running a script after the installation of each external package).

Comment: That's a bug in `wget` which you might want to report.

Comment: @fkraiem Based on my update, do you think that still constitutes a bug? In other words, should `wget` have the contents of `libpsl` compiled in rather than linking to the shared copy if it is seemingly this easy to break?

Comment: Do you mean you are using `LD_PRELOAD` or suchlike? In that case, those are probably the cause of your problem, not a bug in wget.

Comment: @fkraiem Yeah, I'm modifying `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.